# How do I fetch the data using multiple cursors and multiple loops in MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

As per the use case, this procedure should return 30 rows with 15 unique lead id's corresponding to all 15 in activity=1; randomly 10 participate in activity = 2; and from those 10, 5 leads randomly correspond to activity=3.

When I run the stored procedure, it goes on until populating 25 records; which correspond to uniquely getting 15 id's for activity=1 and 10 out of them for activity=2; but, I am unable to fetch the records right after.

If you check down in the code; I have mentioned a SELECT statement just before closing cur2 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task2), which should return Count=25; but it's not. So, apparently, the program isn't even going further into the cur3 which I have declared for activity=3.

I have tried using Continue Handler with cursor, too; but it didn't seem to work!

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task2;
        CREATE TABLE `task2` (
                    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                    `url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                    `lead_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                    `createdDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                    `month` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                    `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                    `month_year` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
                           )

```
BEGIN
    -- INSERTING DATA FOR ACTIVITY = 1

            DECLARE nurl VARCHAR(100);
            DECLARE nleadid INTEGER;
            DECLARE ncreateddate DATETIME;

            DECLARE l_count INTEGER;
            DECLARE loop_count INTEGER;

   -- LOOP COUNT = 15
            SET l_count = 15;

            SET loop_count = 1; 

            read_loop:LOOP

            IF loop_count > l_count THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF; 


            IF loop_count = 1
            THEN
            SET nleadid = 100;
            SET ncreateddate = ('2012-09-08 01:09:30');             

            ELSE
            SET nleadid = 100 + loop_count - 1;
            SET ncreateddate = (SELECT MAX(createdDate) FROM task2);
            SET ncreateddate = DATE_ADD(ncreateddate, INTERVAL ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, '3', '5', '45', '34', '23', '68') MINUTE);                                      
            END IF;


            SET nurl = ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 3, 'g.com', 'y.com', 'm.com');

            INSERT INTO task2 (type_id, url, lead_id, createdDate)
            VALUES ('1', nurl, nleadid, ncreateddate);

            UPDATE task2
            SET month = MONTHNAME(createddate), year = YEAR(createddate), month_year = CONCAT(MONTHNAME(createddate),'-', YEAR(createddate));

            SET loop_count = loop_count + 1;

            END LOOP read_loop;

    END;

    -- INSERTING THE DATA FOR ACTIVITY = 2 
    BEGIN

                DECLARE nurl VARCHAR(100);
                DECLARE nleadid INTEGER;
                DECLARE ncreateddate DATETIME;

                DECLARE l_count INTEGER;
                DECLARE loop_count INTEGER;

        -- CURSOR DECLARATION TO FETCH 10 RANDOM RECORDS FROM ACTIVITY=1

                DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR
                SELECT DISTINCT lead_id FROM task2 WHERE type_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;


                SET l_count = 10;

                SET loop_count = 1; 

                OPEN cur2;



                read_loop:LOOP

                FETCH cur2 INTO nleadid;

                IF loop_count > l_count THEN
                SELECT loop_count_2, l_count_2;
                LEAVE read_loop;
                END IF; 


                SET nurl = ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 3, 'g.com', 'y.com', 'm.com');

                SET ncreateddate = (SELECT MAX(createdDate) FROM task2 WHERE lead_id = nleadid);
                SET ncreateddate = DATE_ADD(ncreateddate, INTERVAL ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, '3', '5', '45', '34', '23', '68') MINUTE);

                INSERT INTO task2 (type_id, url, lead_id, createdDate)
                VALUES ('2', nurl, nleadid, ncreateddate);

                UPDATE task2
                SET month = MONTHNAME(createddate), year = YEAR(createddate), month_year = CONCAT(MONTHNAME(createddate),'-', YEAR(createddate));

                SET loop_count = loop_count + 1;
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task2;
                END LOOP read_loop;

        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task2;
    CLOSE cur2;

END;

-- INSERTING DATA FOR ACTIVITY = 3
    BEGIN

            DECLARE nurl VARCHAR(100);
            DECLARE nleadid INTEGER;
            DECLARE ncreateddate DATETIME;
            DECLARE l_count INTEGER;
            DECLARE loop_count INTEGER;


   -- CURSOR DECLARATION FOR SELECTING 5 RANDOM LEADS FROM ACTIVITY=2     

            DECLARE cur3 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT lead_id FROM task2 WHERE type_id = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;

            SET l_count = 5;

            SET loop_count = 1; 


            OPEN cur3;
            read_loop:LOOP

            IF loop_count > l_count THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF; 

            FETCH cur3 INTO nleadid;

            SET nurl = CONCAT(ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 3, 'g.com', 'y.com', 'm.com'), ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 3, '/home.html', '/index.html', '/about.html'));
            SELECT nurl;              
            SET ncreateddate = (SELECT MAX(createdDate) FROM task2 WHERE lead_id = nleadid);

            SET ncreateddate = DATE_ADD(ncreateddate, INTERVAL ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, '3', '5', '45', '34', '23', '68') MINUTE);

SELECT ncreateddate;     

            INSERT INTO task2 (type_id, url, lead_id, createdDate)
            VALUES ('3', nurl, nleadid, ncreateddate);

            UPDATE task2 
            SET month = MONTHNAME(createddate), year = YEAR(createddate), month_year = CONCAT(MONTHNAME(createddate),'-',YEAR(createddate));

            SET loop_count =loop_count + 1;
            END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE cur3;
END;

    SELECT * FROM task2;
```

END

Comment: You have no [handlers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html) for your cursors, so my best guess is that one of your cursors runs out of rows without a (continue) handler for that. It shouldn't be an issue if all your loops would be proper, so I assume some loop isn't counting correctly; but your code is both too unreadable (no proper indentation, 10s of blank lines, no comments) and not executable (`task1` is unknown) to make it easy enough for us to pinpoint it for you. (Although you can probably debug it with that information if you don't want to improve your code).

Comment: I have the added the code for creating the task2 table as per the use case, though I have tried using the continue handlers, it still didn't seem to work; can you check otherwise?

Comment: Well, your code still does not include continue handlers. They really only work if you actually add them. So please actually do that (or ask how to do that), even if you do not believe (yet) that they will help.